# Should I build a custom text editor from scratch or enhance existing ones?

Tags: design, architecture, windows, wpf

I'm developing a Windows WPF app that needs to edit a certain type of document and I need a highly customized editor to do so:

[image]

The text is a transcription of an audio feed, and I need to sync the the text with a time code of the corresponding word in the audio stream (red numbers on left). This may involve breaking text not at a carriage return (not actually present in my text), but based on a custom timing algorithm (as shown).

I also want custom cursor logic, for instance, having `CTRL + ->` jumping ahead 10 seconds at a time (however many letters that may be). I will also need to format individual words and phrases in various ways.

My question is: do I build from scratch or enhance an existing text editor (TextBox, RichTextBox, FlowDocument, etc.)?

If I use an existing control, I will get powerful features built in, but may run into design limitations--such as default line breaking--that will make it difficult to implement my requirements, or at least I may have to fight the default implementation.

If I roll my own low level control, I have total control but I have to implement everything myself.

How shall I make this decision?

Comment: Line wrapping/breaking behavior is usually a configurable behavior, even for existing text editors because different people have different preferences regarding line wrapping/breaking. It's not uncommon to configure text editors to wrap/break differently for different file types or different projects, so at least in this particular aspect you should be fine.

Comment: @LieRyan: this wouldn't be something configurable like break when matching some pattern. Every line would break at a programmatically determined spot, so I'm not sure this would quite apply.

Comment: Can you do what you want to do by developing a custom mode for GNU Emacs?  Admittedly, you would have to learn GNU Emacs LISP, if you don't already know it, but that isn't that big a deal.

Comment: How long would it take to knock up a simple prototype using your existing control, so that you could find out if any "design limitations" exist?

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: I am pretty sure GNU Emacs won't integrate well as a control into a WPF application.

Comment: It seems you don't need a control with line breaking, quite the opposite. You need a control to hold the text of **one** line with individual formatting of words, which you can put into a table. A `TextBox` is not well suited because AFAIK it does not support the latter. A `RichTextBox` supports that, but you will need to fiddle around with the PageWidth to prevent line breaking, suppressing line breaks this is not well supported.

Comment: ... See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0734f62c-9495-4197-bf14-b0e9a537c590/richtextbox-how-to?forum=wpf

Comment: @DocBrown: Good point.